# How to set winsock accept function timeout?

Tags: timeout, winsock

I'm on my way to write a win32 console application that act as a server. I have to set a timeout to accept function, like without connection in 10s the port shutdown. As I know, there's some way here:

1. Async way. But I'm writing a console application so I can't use that wsaasyncselect function.
2. With select function. But there's word that this way is not safe. If a client sent a RST package and then it offline, the select function think that this socket is still readable, and the accept function will be hold there forever.
3. With alarm function. Firstly I try not to use it because it's unexpected in such a application, secondly I'm worried about whether it's threadsafe or not.

So here I'm asking you sincerely to find a way to let the accept function timeout, who must be threadsafe, and better a nice way.

Comment: Make the socket non-blocking, and use `select`. If there is nothing to accept then `accept` should return an error and `WSAGetLastError` should return `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: Also, according to the [documentation of `accept`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526(v=vs.85).aspx), if the connection was terminated before you call `accept` it should return with error `WSAECONNRESET`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: even if the socket is blocking, you can still use `select()` before calling `accept()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the socket non-blocking (as @JoachimPileborg suggests).

The call to make the socket non-blocking is [ioctlsocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the FIONBIO parameter.

There's an example program [here](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancediomethod5a.html).